# <img> within <span> fails with IE but works well in chrome & mozilla

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, jsf

I have follow following code in my JSF application

```
<t:dataList id="slider-one" value="#{MyBean.banners}" var="ofr" layout="simple" first="0" rows="10" dir="LTR">
<img src="demo/4.jpg" alt="picture" />
</t:dataList>
```

which generates following code on execution:

```
<span id="slider-one" style="display:inline">
<img src="demo/4.jpg" alt="picture" />                                            
<img src="demo/4.jpg" alt="picture" />
</span>
```

I am using JQuery to slide these images which works well in Chrome & Mozilla but fails in IE. Does anyone have any suggestion for this?

Comment: could try display:inline-block since span by default is inline, but thats just a random off the wall guess honestly.

Comment: yap display:block should do but it's bed practice in general to put block objects in inline one.

Comment: post some CSS and JS to please PS: spans are displayed inline by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `<t:dataList layout="simple">` with any attribute which *needs* to be emitted into the HTML, like `id="slider-one"`, then it will render a containing `<span>` element with that attribute.

As answered by RobB, you rather want to use a containing block element instead like `<ul>` with each image inside a `<li>`. To achieve that with [Tomahawk's `<t:dataList>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_dataList.html), you need to set the `layout` attribute to `unorderedList` like so:

```html
<t:dataList id="slider-one" value="#{MyBean.banners}" var="ofr" layout="unorderedList" first="0" rows="10" dir="LTR">
    <h:graphicImage value="#{ofr}" alt="picture" />
</t:dataList>
```

*(note, it was beyond me why you used `<img>` with a fixed `src`, it would only show all the same images, shouldn't you be using a `<h:graphicImage>` referring the `#{ofr}` which I assume represents the image's URL?)*

This will generate HTML like follows:

```html
<ul id="slider-one">
    <li><img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="picture" /></li>
    <li><img src="demo/2.jpg" alt="picture" /></li>
    <li><img src="demo/3.jpg" alt="picture" /></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Most if not all of those jQuery slider plugins/examples are also based on a list of images which is marked up by an `<ul><li>`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, this fixed the issue! I used <img> with fixed <src> just to make it simple as I has lot of other components as well in there, but only img was causing the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your issue correctly, you are trying to create some form of an image slider.  In this case, you should use an `ul` and list each individual image as an `li` element, as a `span` should not really be used to house multiple elements as you are trying to do.  Then wrap a `div` around the `ul` that has `overflow: hidden;` with a specific width set to only expose one of your images at a time.  The `div` will act as a window to view the images within.  You will then slide the `ul` within the `div` to the left or right, according to your desired direction.

If I misunderstood your issue, then my apologies.

Comment: Yes you are correct I am creating image slider. The problem is a java.util.List of images is populated and then I use <t:dataList> for iterating which in fact generates <span>. If I use <ul><li> then this works but <t:dataList> does generates <span><img></span> this works in chrome and mozilla but fails only in IE